# Reverse words of string by recursion

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers, recursion

I'm trying to write a C function that takes a string, and return a new string with reversed words. For example, entering "How are you" should return "you are How". The following is my trial:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char *reverseWords(char *str, char *ac)
{
    if (!ac)
    {
        ac = malloc(strlen(str) + 1);
        ac[0] = '\0';
    }

    char *word = strtok(str, " ");
    if (!word)
    {
        return ac;
    }
    reverseWords(NULL, ac);
    strcat(ac, word);
    //strcat(ac, " ");
}

int main()
{
    char s[] = "How are you";
    char *reversed = reverseWords(s, NULL);
    printf("%s\n", reversed);
}
```

The previous code prints: "youareHow", so it seems that the idea is correct but just missing spaces. If I tried to uncomment the last line int the function, I don't get any output. so what's happening ? I can't understand why it didn't work.

Comment: ac[0] = '\0'; will always run, is that what you want?

Comment: The spaces are loss because `strtok` points after the spaces between words (as you specified in `strtok` call). Then you have to print a space modifying the `printf`: `printf("%s \n", reversed);`

Comment: I can't believe that function doesn't issue you a phat warning about not having all code paths provide an affirmative return value.

Comment: @SirJoBlack, I didn't get your point.

Comment: You can check the following https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42549862/reversing-string-in-c-using-recursion or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12707278/reversing-a-string-in-c-with-recursion

Comment: @WhozCraig,The function will always return a value. the strtok would return a null pointer at some point.

Comment: @RishikeshRaje, I'm not looking for reversing the string, but reversing the words.
I mean that "How are you" should return "you are How" not "uoy era woH". and I'm asking about my specific implementation. Why it doesn't work.

Comment: I often ask this as an interview question!  Don't forget to free your allocations...

Comment: @EddInglis, You're correct about that. I should free the allocation, but this is a secondary point not related to the real problem.

Comment: @Fredrik, Thanks for noticing that. It's not what I want. but even after wrapping the two statement between curly braces the same happens. This even getting me more crazy about how it was partially-working without the braces. Anyway, I edited the question and added the braces.

Comment: "The function will always return a value."  No it won't.  After your commented line, execution falls off the bottom without explicitly returning a value.  Now it is true to say that it will return _something_ but it'll be undefined.  That's really what @WhozCraig meant.  That should be your first priority to fix, right after adjusting your compiler settings to warn you (-Wall).

Comment: *"The function will always return a value."* - orly ? what does it return when the result `strtok` is *not* null ? Um...

Comment: Yes, is not correct my assertion :) . You have to add a space into the function between the words because strtok removed the spaces. You have to add `strcat(ac, " ");` after    `strcat(ac, word);` ... Furthermore is better the functions terminates with `return ac` (to be verified).

Comment: @WhozCraig, Oh. Yes I see. I think the line `reverseWords(NULL, ac);` should be `return reverseWords(NULL, ac);`. but even after I added return to that line, it's still not working.

Comment: After added the return, it won't work because the strcat won't be executed.

Comment: You don't need to do this with `strtok` or any dynamic memory allocation. it can be done recursive, and entirely in-place. If you're the least bit keen in wanting to know how, let me know.

Comment: I managed to get it working. https://onlinegdb.com/HJE1EnqsS.

@WhozCraig, Yes please, I surely want to know the easier way.

Comment: If the requirements dictate the string cannot be modified, then dynamic allocation is your only route. But if the string can be modified in place, you can use *reverse partitioning* to accomplish this. [An example can be seen here](https://ideone.com/wtndWM).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are neglecting the return value of `reverseWords`. I think this is ok because you have reference to `ac`

At the end of `reverseWords` function you are not returning `ac` which holds the contcatinated string.

Now you have to uncomment `strcat(ac, " ");` so that space will be added to the return value.

Now the return value will have the reversed string with spaces in it.

You forgot to free the allocated string.

Comment: Still not working for me:
https://onlinegdb.com/H1NtG3qoS
it's even now not working in both cases, with the last line commented and not commented.

Comment: For the code in the link, it won't work because the strcat won't be executed. because of the added return.

Answer (score 2):

When you recursively call `reverseWords` you ignore the return code, but this is no problem as the higher level invocation already has a reference to `ac`.

But the highest level invocation will leave the function `reverseWords` at its end where you forgot to return a value.

When your program seems to work partially by printing "youareHow", you actually observed undefined behavior because the `main` function apparently found the address of the expected string where it expects to get the return value. As the function does not return a value, this is something left over in memory or in a register from the previously executed code.

Change your code like this:

```
    char *word = strtok(str, " ");
    if (!word)
    {
        return ac;
    }
    reverseWords(NULL, ac);
    strcat(ac, word);
    strcat(ac, " ");
    return ac;
}
```

Note that your code appends a space after every word.
You can see this if you change the output as

```
    printf("<%s>\n", reversed);
```

To fix this you can replace

```
    strcat(ac, word);
    strcat(ac, " ");
```

with

```
    if(ac[0] != '\0')
    {
        strcat(ac, " ");
    }
    strcat(ac, word);
```

This will insert a space before every word if the existing string in `ac` is not empty.

Comment: Great! Thanks for the tip on fixing the last space problem as well. :)

Answer (score 2):

I'm adding this only because sooner or later the alternative approach link I propped up on ideone.com will rot, and when it does, people may wonder wth I was talking about in general comment.

This task can be done *in-place*, without dynamic allocation or usage of `strtok`. The approach uses a technique caled *reversal partitioning*, and is accomplished by doing the following:

1. Locate the first whitespace from the beginning of the string to the end-marker, which is initially provided as the terminator, (but will be reduced with each recursion). If no whitespace is found in that segment, you're done.
2. Reverse the segment from the beginning of the string to, but not including the breaking whitespace discovered from (1).
3. Reverse the *entire* sequence from beginning to end-marker.
4. Reverse the segment from the beginning of the string to the position immediately prior to the whitespace before the moved segment.
5. Recurse using using segment not including the data just moved, nor it's leading whitespace.

That's it. now to see it with data:

```
step 1,2. reverse the target sequence
"abc 123 xyz" ==> "cba 123 xyz"
 ^^^               ^^^

step 3. Reverse the entire sequence
"cba 123 xyz" ==> "zyx 321 abc"

step 3 Reverse the non-target sequence, not including the trailing space
"zyx 321 abc" => "123 xyz abc"
 ^^^^^^^           ^^^^^^^
```

Repeat this (recursion or iteration, makes no difference) for the non-target segment, adjusting the end-marker to do so. A second walk through would look like this, noting the position of the end-marker `*` *above* the examples:

```
        *                *
"123 xyz abc" => "321 xyz abc"
 ^^^              ^^^

        *                *
"321 xyz abc" => "zyx 123 abc"
 ^^^^^^^          ^^^^^^^

        *                *
"zyx 123 abc" => "xyz 123 abc"
 ^^^              ^^^
```

Once this is done, recurse again. Now the intro looks like this:

```
    *
"xyz 123 abc"
```

but note there is no whitespace between the beginning of string and the end-marker, so we're done (and we are, in case you missed it).

---

**The Code**

The actual code to do this is straightforward, only the pointer math takes a few stares to fully understand. Here it is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

void reverse_letters(char *beg, char *end)
{
    while (beg < --end)
    {
        char tmp = *beg;
        *beg++ = *end;
        *end = tmp;
    }
}

char *reverse_words(char *beg, char *end)
{
    // find whitespace. if none then we're done.
    char *p = beg;
    for (; p != end && !isspace((unsigned char)*p); ++p);

    if (p != end)
    {
        reverse_letters(beg, p);
        reverse_letters(beg, end);
        reverse_letters(beg, beg + (end - p - 1));
        reverse_words(beg, beg + (end - p - 1));
    }

    return beg;
}

int main()
{
    char words[] = "abc 123 xyz";
    reverse_words(words, words + strlen(words));
    puts(words);
    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
xyz 123 abc
```

Obviously this is as tail-recursive as one can get, and therefore would be trivial to adapt to an iterative solution, which I leave as an exercise for the reader(s).